# Error while creating train transform using torch vision

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am using torch vision to create the following train transformation. I do not understand what's wrong and how I can fix it?

```
train_transform = torch.nn.Sequential(
    transforms.ToTensor(), 
    transforms.RandomApply([
         transforms.RandomApply([transforms.RandomRotation(15)], 0.6),
         transforms.RandomApply([transforms.RandomAffine(0, shear=0.2)], 0.3),
         transforms.RandomApply([transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size = 224, scale=(0.8, 1.4))], 0.7)
        ], p= 0.5)
)
```

This is the error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 5          transforms.RandomApply([transforms.RandomAffine(0, shear=0.2)], 0.3),
> 6          transforms.RandomApply([transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size = 224,
> scale=(0.8, 1.4))], 0.7)
> ----> 7         ], p= 0.5)
> 8 )
>
> 1 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in
> add_module(self, name, module)
> 371         if not isinstance(module, Module) and module is not None:
> 372             raise TypeError("{} is not a Module subclass".format(
> --> 373                 torch.typename(module)))
> 374         elif not isinstance(name, torch._six.string_classes):
> 375             raise TypeError("module name should be a string. Got {}".format(
>
> TypeError: torchvision.transforms.transforms.ToTensor is not a Module
> subclass

Comment: Do you want to use ```transforms.Compose```instead of ```torch.nn.Sequential```?  ```torch.nn.Sequential``` is commonly used to build your model and not to create transformations of your data

Comment: @yuki Yes, but I want these transformations to happen in order. see https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#scriptable-transforms

Comment: I updated my answer so that you can script your transformations, which is the main purpose of the ```torch.nn.Sequential``` function. How I understand it from the documentation it should, however, not make a difference whether you script the transformations or use ```transforms.Compose``` since your transformations will in both cases be executed in the order you specify in the function.

Answer (score 2):

`torch.nn.Sequential` scripts your transformations. You can only use scriptable transformations in `torch.nn.Sequential` and `transforms.ToTensor()` is not a scriptable transformation.
A scriptable transformation only takes a Tensor as an input. This is why you cannot use `transforms.ToTensor()` in the `torch.nn.Sequential` function, as you take an some data as input and transform it to a tensor.

You can find this information in the PyTorch documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/transforms.html) under Scriptable Transformations.  The `transforms.RandomApply` transformation is also not scriptable but it says [here in the transforms.visions docu](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/transforms/transforms.html) how to use it in a scriptable way anyway (see the definition of the class `RandomApply`). In the source code it says: " In order to script the transformation, please use `torch.nn.ModuleList` as input instead of list/tuple of transforms"

You have to wrap all your random transformations with `torch.nn.ModuleList`.

```
my_transforms = transforms.RandomApply(torch.nn.ModuleList([
     transforms.RandomApply( torch.nn.ModuleList([ transforms.RandomRotation(15)]), p=0.6),
     transforms.RandomApply( torch.nn.ModuleList([ transforms.RandomAffine(0, shear=0.2)]), p=0.3),
     transforms.RandomApply( torch.nn.ModuleList([ transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size = 224, scale=(0.8, 1.4))]), p=0.7),

 ]), p=0.3)
scripted_transforms = torch.jit.script(my_transforms)
```

If you want to, you can also wrap these transformations with `torch.nn.Sequential` but it is not necessary. Then the code should be this:

```
my_transforms = torch.nn.Sequential(transforms.RandomApply(torch.nn.ModuleList([
     transforms.RandomApply( torch.nn.ModuleList([ transforms.RandomRotation(15)]), p=0.6),
     transforms.RandomApply( torch.nn.ModuleList([ transforms.RandomAffine(0, shear=0.2)]), p=0.3),
     transforms.RandomApply( torch.nn.ModuleList([ transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size = 224, scale=(0.8, 1.4))]), p=0.7),

 ]), p=0.3))
scripted_transforms = torch.jit.script(my_transforms)
```

As mentioned, the tensor transformation cannot be added to this, since it is not scriptable.

Another solution is to use the `transforms.Compose` instead of `torch.nn.Sequential` like this:

```
from torchvision import transforms
train_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(), 
    transforms.RandomApply([
         transforms.RandomApply([transforms.RandomRotation(15)], 0.6),
         transforms.RandomApply([transforms.RandomAffine(0, shear=0.2)], 0.3),
         transforms.RandomApply([transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size = 224, scale=(0.8, 1.4))], 0.7)
        ], p= 0.5)
])
```

In both cases the complete list of transformations will be randomly applied to your data, exactly in the order as you have specified the transformations in the list. You can see this from the [source code](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/transforms/transforms.html) of Random.Apply, where the forward pass looks like this

```
def forward(self, img):
        if self.p < torch.rand(1):
            return img
        for t in self.transforms:
            img = t(img)
        return img
```

The function loops over all transformations `t` in `self.transforms` exactly in the order you have specified in the list. So technically it is not necessary that you use `torch.nn.Sequential`.